# Fragment appearing multiple times in tabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I didn't find any relevant posts to this problem. I am trying to implement simple tabs (tab layout) with swipe using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNpWGI_hGGg&list=LLXP4gkzWoIeG2xVp9tCOw1Q&index=5&t=41s). However, my fragment is appearing multiple times even when I click for the first time. Please find below the relevant code. Will appreciate any help provided.

**FragmentPagerAdapter Implementation:**

```
public class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);

}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}
}
```

**Main Class:**

```
SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter = new 
SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter and add fragments.
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

mSectionsPageAdapter.addFragment(new TodayFragment(), "TAB1");
mSectionsPageAdapter.addFragment(new WeeklyFragment(), "TAB2");
mSectionsPageAdapter.addFragment(new PhotosFragment(), "TAB3");
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPageAdapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragments are one liner so I don't think there is any problem there. Please find below 2 screenshots taken 1) onLoading activity 2) after clicking on tab2 for 1st time.

[image]       [image]

Comment: You have not shared button action code, I think you should refresh the adapter when you click the button.

Comment: @FaridHaq I am not doing anything with button (no Listeners attached). Its all about clicking on tabs, no additional behavior.

Comment: Another Observation, I don't know why but my getCount method in FragmentPagerAdapter is called multiple number of times (>20) even though I am clicking only once.

Comment: Is your main class code inside `onCreate()`?

Comment: @Ayush yes it is inside onCreate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you share with us the layout code for your second fragment? Id like to see if the lack of a solid background may be causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks man. Setting android:background="@color/colorPrimary" did the trick. I thought it was inherited. I deeply appreciate your help for finding error in the part which I even didn't think work enough to mention in my question.

Comment: @DevendraSwami This doesn't fix the fact that you have overlapping content. This just hides it.

Comment: @MikeM. True, feel free to suggest a better fix. I feel the overlapping content might be because multiple calls to getCount and rendering view on each count. Not sure though !!!

Comment: @DevendraSwami Yeah, there's not enough information given to determine the actual problem. I was just letting you know that you might have other issues in the future.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for letting me know. Let me know if you want me to add more information to the question. Frankly, I didn't find a similar problem elsewhere and not sure about the root cause.

Comment: Glad it worked! And the overlapping content is not an issue. If you are using fragments you will have a fragment back stack that holds the fragments and their views in memory i believe. You can see this in any application by making the background transparent if you are using .add() with the fragment manager